# How to validate a class added dynamically with jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-validate

I have a form that display a list of items that are retrieved from the database. Each of them has a degree of 'intensity'.

So, the user has to mark the chosen items in checkboxes and, for each chosen item, he has to choose a degree of intensity.

See how it looks: http://prntscr.com/citz8y

The problem is: validating it is a nightmare. I have to register all of this using a foreach, wich means all the radio buttons share the same name. What I need to do is: when user marks an item, only the radio buttons of that item will be required - the rest will remain as it is.

I've already tried putting a function on the checkboxes that marks the radio with a class, so jQuery will know what to validate. The class is added successfully just where it is necessary. However, the validation fails.

See my code:

**jQuery Validation:**

```
$('.manter-em.marcado').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required:  'Marque o grau de agravamento a ser mantido'
        }
    });
});
```

**Function to add Class:**

```
function marcaRadios(elem)
{

    if($(elem).is(':checked'))
    {

        $(elem).parent().parent().parent().find('.form-group.required input').addClass('marcado');
    }
    else
    {
        $(elem).parent().parent().parent().removeClass('marcado');
    }
}
```

**Form:**

```
<form name="frm_cadastrar" action="sugerir_resultados.php?acao=<?=codificaURL("inserir")?>&id=<?=codificaURL($id)?>" method="post">
    <?php       
    while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
    ?>
    <fieldset class="drop-list">
        <legend><?=$linhas["titulo"]?> <span class="caret"></span></legend>
        <div class="dropdown-list">
            <?php
            $q1 = mysqli_query($con, "select r.id as id_resultado, r.titulo, s.id, r.idade_minima, r.idade_maxima, r.unidade from resultados r, solucoes s where r.id = s.codresultado AND s.coddiagnostico = ".$linhas["id"]);
            while($resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($q1)):

            if(!empty($resultados["unidade"])){
                $idade = 0; $idade_minima = 0; $idade_maxima = 0;
                $idade_minima = $resultados["idade_minima"];
                $idade_maxima = $resultados["idade_maxima"];

                if($resultados["unidade"]=="A")
                {
                        $idade_minima = $resultados["idade_minima"]*12;
                        if(!empty($idade_maxima))
                        {
                            $idade_maxima = $resultados["idade_maxima"]*12;
                        }
                }

                $q2 = mysqli_query($con, "select idade, unidade from criancas c, consultas cs where c.id = cs.codcrianca AND cs.id = $id");
                if($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($q2))
                {
                    $idade = $linhas["idade"];

                    if($linhas["unidade"]=="A")
                    {
                        $idade = $idade*12;
                    }

                    if(!empty($idade_maxima))
                    {
                        if($idade>=$idade_minima && $idade<=$idade_maxima)
                        {
                        ?>
                        <div class="opcao-resultado">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type='checkbox' name='solucoes[]' onclick="marcaRadios(this)" value="<?=$resultados["id"]?>">
                                    <a href='exibir_resultado.php?id=<?=codificaURL($resultados["id_resultado"])?>'>
                                        <?=$resultados["titulo"]?>
                                    </a>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <hr class="hr-checkbox">
                            <div class="form-group required">
                                <label for="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>">Manter em&nbsp;</label>                                    
                                <input type="radio" name="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>" id="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>" class="manter-em" value="1"> 1 (Gravemente comprometido)
                                <input type="radio" name="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>" class="manter-em" value="2"> 2 (Muito comprometido)
                                <input type="radio" name="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>" class="manter-em" value="3"> 3 (Moderadamente comprometido)
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group required"> 
                                <label for="<?="aumentar_para".$resultados["id"]?>">Aumentar para&nbsp;</label>                                    
                                <input type="radio" name="<?="aumentar_para".$resultados["id"]?>" id="<?="aumentar_para".$resultados["id"]?>" class="aumentar-para" value="4"> 4 (Levemente comprometido)
                                <input type="radio" name="<?="aumentar_para".$resultados["id"]?>" class="aumentar-para" value="5"> 5 (N&atilde;o comprometido)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <?php
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if($idade==$idade_minima){
                        ?>
                        <div class="opcao-resultado">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type='checkbox' name='solucoes[]' onclick="marcaRadios(this)" value="<?=$resultados["id"]?>">
                                    <a href='exibir_resultado.php?id=<?=codificaURL($resultados["id_resultado"])?>'>
                                        <?=$resultados["titulo"]?>
                                    </a>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <hr class="hr-checkbox">
                            <div class="form-group required">
                                <label for="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>">Manter em&nbsp;</label>                                    
                                <input type="radio" name="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>" id="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>" class="manter-em" value="1"> 1 (Gravemente comprometido)
                                <input type="radio" name="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>" class="manter-em" value="2"> 2 (Muito comprometido)
                                <input type="radio" name="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>" class="manter-em" value="3"> 3 (Moderadamente comprometido)
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group required"> 
                                <label for="<?="aumentar_para".$resultados["id"]?>">Aumentar para&nbsp;</label>                                    
                                <input type="radio" name="<?="aumentar_para".$resultados["id"]?>" id="<?="aumentar_para".$resultados["id"]?>" class="aumentar-para" value="4"> 4 (Levemente comprometido)
                                <input type="radio" name="<?="aumentar_para".$resultados["id"]?>" class="aumentar-para" value="5"> 5 (N&atilde;o comprometido)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {?>
                <div class="opcao-resultado">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='solucoes[]' onclick="marcaRadios(this)" value="<?=$resultados["id"]?>">
                            <a href='exibir_resultado.php?id=<?=codificaURL($resultados["id_resultado"])?>'>
                                <?=$resultados["titulo"]?>
                            </a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-checkbox">
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label for="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>">Manter em&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>" id="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>" class="manter-em" value="1"> 1 (Gravemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>" class="manter-em" value="2"> 2 (Muito comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="<?="manter_em".$resultados["id"]?>" class="manter-em" value="3"> 3 (Moderadamente comprometido)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required"> 
                        <label for="<?="aumentar_para".$resultados["id"]?>">Aumentar para&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="<?="aumentar_para".$resultados["id"]?>" id="<?="aumentar_para".$resultados["id"]?>" class="aumentar-para" value="4"> 4 (Levemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="<?="aumentar_para".$resultados["id"]?>" class="aumentar-para" value="5"> 5 (N&atilde;o comprometido)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
            <?php
            }

            endwhile;
            ?>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?php }?>
    <button type="submit" name="enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active acao">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> 
        Salvar
    </button>
    <button type="reset" name="limpar" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span> 
        Limpar
    </button>
</form>
```

**HTML as rendered in the browser:**

```
 <form name="frm_cadastrar" action="sugerir_resultados.php?acao=aW5zZXJpcg,,&id=MTg," method="post">
            <fieldset class="drop-list">
        <legend>Risco de integridade da pele prejudicada <span class="caret"></span></legend>
        <div class="dropdown-list">
                                <div class="opcao-resultado">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='solucoes[]' onclick="marcaRadios(this)" value="232">
                            <a href='exibir_resultado.php?id=MTAwNA,,'>
                                Estado Nutricional                                </a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-checkbox">
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label for="manter_em232">Manter em&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em232" id="manter_em232" class="manter-em" value="1"> 1 (Gravemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em232" class="manter-em" value="2"> 2 (Muito comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em232" class="manter-em" value="3"> 3 (Moderadamente comprometido)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required"> 
                        <label for="aumentar_para232">Aumentar para&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para232" id="aumentar_para232" class="aumentar-para" value="4"> 4 (Levemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para232" class="aumentar-para" value="5"> 5 (N&atilde;o comprometido)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                                <div class="opcao-resultado">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='solucoes[]' onclick="marcaRadios(this)" value="233">
                            <a href='exibir_resultado.php?id=MTEwMQ,,'>
                                Integridade Tissular: Pele e Mucosa                                </a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-checkbox">
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label for="manter_em233">Manter em&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em233" id="manter_em233" class="manter-em" value="1"> 1 (Gravemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em233" class="manter-em" value="2"> 2 (Muito comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em233" class="manter-em" value="3"> 3 (Moderadamente comprometido)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required"> 
                        <label for="aumentar_para233">Aumentar para&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para233" id="aumentar_para233" class="aumentar-para" value="4"> 4 (Levemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para233" class="aumentar-para" value="5"> 5 (N&atilde;o comprometido)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                                <div class="opcao-resultado">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='solucoes[]' onclick="marcaRadios(this)" value="234">
                            <a href='exibir_resultado.php?id=MTEwMg,,'>
                                Cicatrização de Feridas: primeira intenção                                </a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-checkbox">
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label for="manter_em234">Manter em&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em234" id="manter_em234" class="manter-em" value="1"> 1 (Gravemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em234" class="manter-em" value="2"> 2 (Muito comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em234" class="manter-em" value="3"> 3 (Moderadamente comprometido)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required"> 
                        <label for="aumentar_para234">Aumentar para&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para234" id="aumentar_para234" class="aumentar-para" value="4"> 4 (Levemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para234" class="aumentar-para" value="5"> 5 (N&atilde;o comprometido)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                                <div class="opcao-resultado">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='solucoes[]' onclick="marcaRadios(this)" value="235">
                            <a href='exibir_resultado.php?id=MTEwMw,,'>
                                Cicatrização de Feridas: segunda intenção                                </a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-checkbox">
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label for="manter_em235">Manter em&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em235" id="manter_em235" class="manter-em" value="1"> 1 (Gravemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em235" class="manter-em" value="2"> 2 (Muito comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em235" class="manter-em" value="3"> 3 (Moderadamente comprometido)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required"> 
                        <label for="aumentar_para235">Aumentar para&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para235" id="aumentar_para235" class="aumentar-para" value="4"> 4 (Levemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para235" class="aumentar-para" value="5"> 5 (N&atilde;o comprometido)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                                <div class="opcao-resultado">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='solucoes[]' onclick="marcaRadios(this)" value="236">
                            <a href='exibir_resultado.php?id=MTEwNg,,'>
                                Cicatrização de Queimaduras                                </a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-checkbox">
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label for="manter_em236">Manter em&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em236" id="manter_em236" class="manter-em" value="1"> 1 (Gravemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em236" class="manter-em" value="2"> 2 (Muito comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em236" class="manter-em" value="3"> 3 (Moderadamente comprometido)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required"> 
                        <label for="aumentar_para236">Aumentar para&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para236" id="aumentar_para236" class="aumentar-para" value="4"> 4 (Levemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para236" class="aumentar-para" value="5"> 5 (N&atilde;o comprometido)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                                <div class="opcao-resultado">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='solucoes[]' onclick="marcaRadios(this)" value="237">
                            <a href='exibir_resultado.php?id=MTEwNw,,'>
                                Recuperação de Queimaduras                                </a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-checkbox">
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label for="manter_em237">Manter em&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em237" id="manter_em237" class="manter-em" value="1"> 1 (Gravemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em237" class="manter-em" value="2"> 2 (Muito comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em237" class="manter-em" value="3"> 3 (Moderadamente comprometido)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required"> 
                        <label for="aumentar_para237">Aumentar para&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para237" id="aumentar_para237" class="aumentar-para" value="4"> 4 (Levemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para237" class="aumentar-para" value="5"> 5 (N&atilde;o comprometido)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                                <div class="opcao-resultado">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='solucoes[]' onclick="marcaRadios(this)" value="238">
                            <a href='exibir_resultado.php?id=MTkyMg,,'>
                                Controle de Riscos: hipertermia                                </a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-checkbox">
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label for="manter_em238">Manter em&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em238" id="manter_em238" class="manter-em" value="1"> 1 (Gravemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em238" class="manter-em" value="2"> 2 (Muito comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em238" class="manter-em" value="3"> 3 (Moderadamente comprometido)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required"> 
                        <label for="aumentar_para238">Aumentar para&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para238" id="aumentar_para238" class="aumentar-para" value="4"> 4 (Levemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para238" class="aumentar-para" value="5"> 5 (N&atilde;o comprometido)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                                <div class="opcao-resultado">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='solucoes[]' onclick="marcaRadios(this)" value="239">
                            <a href='exibir_resultado.php?id=MTkyMw,,'>
                                Controle de Riscos: hipotermia                                </a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-checkbox">
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label for="manter_em239">Manter em&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em239" id="manter_em239" class="manter-em" value="1"> 1 (Gravemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em239" class="manter-em" value="2"> 2 (Muito comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em239" class="manter-em" value="3"> 3 (Moderadamente comprometido)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required"> 
                        <label for="aumentar_para239">Aumentar para&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para239" id="aumentar_para239" class="aumentar-para" value="4"> 4 (Levemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para239" class="aumentar-para" value="5"> 5 (N&atilde;o comprometido)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                                <div class="opcao-resultado">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='solucoes[]' onclick="marcaRadios(this)" value="240">
                            <a href='exibir_resultado.php?id=MTkyNA,,'>
                                Controle de Riscos: Processo Infeccioso                                </a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="hr-checkbox">
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label for="manter_em240">Manter em&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em240" id="manter_em240" class="manter-em" value="1"> 1 (Gravemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em240" class="manter-em" value="2"> 2 (Muito comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="manter_em240" class="manter-em" value="3"> 3 (Moderadamente comprometido)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required"> 
                        <label for="aumentar_para240">Aumentar para&nbsp;</label>                                    
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para240" id="aumentar_para240" class="aumentar-para" value="4"> 4 (Levemente comprometido)
                        <input type="radio" name="aumentar_para240" class="aumentar-para" value="5"> 5 (N&atilde;o comprometido)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                        </div>
    </fieldset>
            <button type="submit" name="enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active acao">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> 
        Salvar
    </button>
    <button type="reset" name="limpar" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></span> 
        Limpar
    </button>
</form>
```

**HTML as rendered AFTER user marks a checkbox:**  [link](http://prntscr.com/cj10vt)

Can you please shed me some light in this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put this in a JSFiddle to have a starting point?

Comment: I posted the full code of the page below

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but I'm guessing that you may need to run the JQuery validation logic after the classes have been reassigned. Your JQuery validation logic should also FIRST set all items without that class so their required property is false (set the required items to true afterward).

Comment: You need to show us the HTML markup as ***RENDERED*** in the browser's source, not the PHP.

Comment: @Sparky. Sure, here it is: 1 - HTML as rendered in the browser BEFORE user marks a checkbox: [link](http://prntscr.com/cj0z79). 2 - HTML as rendered AFTER user marks a checkbox:  [link](http://prntscr.com/cj10vt)

Comment: @ChadMcGrath, not sure I get what your saying. '-'